# Simple Brainfuck Interpreter in Rust

Tags: rust, interpreter, brainfuck

Not a long time ago, I got into Rust and I made a simple [Brainfuck Interpreter](https://github.com/DimChtz/brainfuck/tree/master/rust-brainpreter). Now I want to get back to Rust and I would like some comments on my code:

Just in case it's hard to read code from post:

https://github.com/DimChtz/brainfuck/tree/master/rust-brainpreter

**lib.rs**

```
mod core;

use core::parser::Parser;
use core::program::Program;
use core::instruction::Instruction;
use core::error::Error;
use core::memory::Memory;

use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::path::Path;

// Struct for the bf Interpreter (brainpreter)
pub struct Inter {

    tape:Memory,
    program:Program,
    parser:Parser,

}

impl Inter {

    // Function to create and return a new Interpreter
    pub fn new() -> Inter {

        Inter {

            tape: Memory::new(),
            program: Program::new(),
            parser: Parser::new(),

        }

    }

    // Function to load code into the parser (text)
    pub fn load<S: Into<String>>(&mut self, p:S) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.parser.load(p)

    }

    // Function to load code into the parser (file)
    pub fn load_from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(&mut self, src:P) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.parser.load_from_file(src)

    }

    // Function to compile the code
    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        // Call the parser
        match self.parser.parse() {

            Ok(p) => {

                self.program = p;

                Ok(())

            }

            Err(e) => Result::Err(e),

        }

    }

    // Function to execute bf program
    pub fn run(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        // Check if a program is properly loaded
        if self.program.get_size() == 0 {
            return Result::Err(Error::EmptyProgram);
        }

        // Execute instructions
        while let Some(instr) = self.program.get() {

            match instr {

                Instruction::IncPtr => { match self.inc_ptr() { Ok(_) => {  } Err(e) => return Result::Err(e), } }
                Instruction::DecPtr => { match self.dec_ptr() { Ok(_) => {  } Err(e) => return Result::Err(e), } }
                Instruction::IncVal => { match self.inc_val() { Ok(_) => {  } Err(e) => return Result::Err(e), } }
                Instruction::DecVal => { match self.dec_val() { Ok(_) => {  } Err(e) => return Result::Err(e), } }
                Instruction::Input  => { self.input(); }
                Instruction::Output => { self.output(); }
                Instruction::OpenBracket(n)  => { self.open_bracket(n); }
                Instruction::CloseBracket(n) => { self.close_bracket(n); }

            };

            // If this was the last instruction
            if !self.program.inc_ptr() {
                break;
            }

        };

        return Result::Ok(());

    }

    // Function to increase the value on the memory (tape)
    fn inc_val(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.tape.inc_val()

    }

    // Function to decrease the value on the memory (tape)
    fn dec_val(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.tape.dec_val()

    }

    // Function to increase the pointer on the memory (tape)
    fn inc_ptr(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.tape.inc_ptr()

    }

    // Function to decrease the pointer on the memory (tape)
    fn dec_ptr(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.tape.dec_ptr()

    }

    // Function to read into the memory (tape)
    fn input(&mut self) {

        match io::stdin().bytes().next() {

            Some(v) => self.tape.set_val(v.unwrap()),

            None => {  }

        }

    }

    // Function to print a char from memory (tape)
    fn output(&mut self) {

        print!("{}", self.tape.get_val() as char);

    }

    // Function to handle the open bracket
    fn open_bracket(&mut self, pos:usize) {

        if self.tape.get_val() == 0 {
            self.program.set_ptr(pos);
        }

    }

    // Function to handle the close bracket
    fn close_bracket(&mut self, pos:usize) {

        if self.tape.get_val() != 0 {
            self.program.set_ptr(pos);
        }

    }

}
```

**core/mod.rs**

```
pub mod instruction;
pub mod program;
pub mod parser;
pub mod error;
pub mod memory;
```

**core/error.rs**

```
use std::error;
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {

    NoSuchFile,
    EmptyProgram,
    MissingOpenBracket,
    MissingCloseBracket,
    PtrOverflow,
    PtrUnderflow,
    ValOverflow,
    ValUnderflow,

}

impl error::Error for Error {

    fn description(&self) -> &str {

        match *self {

            Error::NoSuchFile => "Failed to open file",
            Error::EmptyProgram => "The program is empty",
            Error::MissingOpenBracket => "Missing open bracket(s)",
            Error::MissingCloseBracket => "Missing close bracket(s)",
            Error::PtrOverflow => "Memory pointer overflow",
            Error::PtrUnderflow => "Memory pointer underflow",
            Error::ValOverflow => "Memory value overflow",
            Error::ValUnderflow => "Memory value underflow",

        }

    }

}

impl fmt::Display for Error {

    fn fmt(&self, f:&mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {

        match *self {

            Error::NoSuchFile => write!(f, "Couldn't open file."),
            Error::EmptyProgram => write!(f, "The program is empty."),
            Error::MissingOpenBracket => write!(f, "Missing open bracket(s)."),
            Error::MissingCloseBracket => write!(f, "Missing close bracket(s)."),
            Error::PtrOverflow => write!(f,"Memory pointer overflow."),
            Error::PtrUnderflow => write!(f,"Memory pointer underflow."),
            Error::ValOverflow => write!(f,"Memory value overflow."),
            Error::ValUnderflow => write!(f,"Memory value underflow."),

        }

    }

}
```

**core/instruction.rs**

```
use std::fmt::{self, Display};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub enum Instruction {

    IncPtr,
    DecPtr,
    IncVal,
    DecVal,
    Input,
    Output,
    OpenBracket(usize),
    CloseBracket(usize),

}

impl Display for Instruction {

    fn fmt(&self, f:&mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {

        match *self {

            Instruction::IncPtr => write!(f, ">"),
            Instruction::DecPtr => write!(f, "<"),
            Instruction::IncVal => write!(f, "+"),
            Instruction::DecVal => write!(f, "-"),
            Instruction::Input  => write!(f, ","),
            Instruction::Output => write!(f, "."),
            Instruction::OpenBracket(_) => write!(f, "["),
            Instruction::CloseBracket(_) => write!(f, "]"),

        }

    }

}

pub mod mapper {

    use super::Instruction;

    pub fn get_instr(c:char) -> Option<super::Instruction> {

        match c {

            '>' => Option::Some(Instruction::IncPtr),
            '<' => Option::Some(Instruction::DecPtr),
            '+' => Option::Some(Instruction::IncVal),
            '-' => Option::Some(Instruction::DecVal),
            ',' => Option::Some(Instruction::Input),
            '.' => Option::Some(Instruction::Output),
            '[' => Option::Some(Instruction::OpenBracket(0usize)),
            ']' => Option::Some(Instruction::CloseBracket(0usize)),
            _   => Option::None,

        }

    }

    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn get_char(instr:Instruction) -> char {

        match instr {

            Instruction::IncPtr => '>',
            Instruction::DecPtr => '<',
            Instruction::IncVal => '+',
            Instruction::DecVal => '-',
            Instruction::Input => ',',
            Instruction::Output => '.',
            Instruction::OpenBracket(_) => '[',
            Instruction::CloseBracket(_) => ']',

        }

    }

}
```

**core/memory.rs**

```
use super::error::Error;

pub const MEMORY_SIZE:usize = 30000;

// Memory tape
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Memory {

    cells: Vec<u8>,
    ptr:usize,

}

impl Memory {

    // Function to create and return a new Memory tape
    pub fn new() -> Memory {

        let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
        v.push(0);

        Memory {

            cells: v,
            ptr:0,

        }

    }

    // Function to move the pointer to the right
    pub fn inc_ptr(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.ptr += 1;

        match self.ptr {

            n if n >= MEMORY_SIZE => {

                Result::Err(Error::PtrOverflow)

            }

            _ => {

                if self.ptr >= self.cells.len() {

                    self.cells.push(0);

                }

                Result::Ok(())

            }

        }

    }

    // Function to move the poiner to the left
    pub fn dec_ptr(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        match self.ptr {

            n if n == 0 => {

                Result::Err(Error::PtrUnderflow)

            }

            _ => {

                self.ptr -= 1;

                Result::Ok(())

            }

        }

    }

    // Function to increase the value
    pub fn inc_val(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        match self.cells[self.ptr].checked_add(1) {

            Some(v) => {

                self.cells[self.ptr] = v;

                Result::Ok(())

            }

            None => Result::Err(Error::ValOverflow),

        }

    }

    // Function to decrease the value
    pub fn dec_val(&mut self) -> Result<(), Error> {

        match self.cells[self.ptr].checked_sub(1) {

            Some(v) => {

                self.cells[self.ptr] = v;

                Result::Ok(())

            }

            None => Result::Err(Error::ValUnderflow),

        }

    }

    // Function to get the current value
    pub fn get_val(&self) -> u8 {

        self.cells[self.ptr]

    }

    // Function to set the current value
    pub fn set_val(&mut self, v:u8) {

        self.cells[self.ptr] = v;

    }

}
```

**core/parser.rs**

```
use super::instruction::{mapper, Instruction};
use super::program::Program;
use super::error::Error;

use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::fs::File;
use std::path::Path;
use std::convert::AsRef;

pub struct Parser {

    code_buffer:Vec<u8>,

}

impl Parser {

    // Function to create and return a new Parser
    pub fn new() -> Parser {

        Parser {
            code_buffer:Vec::<u8>::new(),
        }

    }

    // Function to load code from simple text
    pub fn load<S: Into<String>>(&mut self, buffer:S) -> Result<(), Error> {

        self.code_buffer = buffer.into().into_bytes();

        match self.code_buffer.len() {

            l if l > 0 => Result::Ok(()),

            _ => Result::Err(Error::EmptyProgram),

        }

    }

    // Function to load code from a file
    pub fn load_from_file<P: AsRef<Path>>(&mut self, src:P) -> Result<(), Error> {

        match File::open(src) {

            Ok(mut file) => {

                let mut content = String::new();

                match file.read_to_string(&mut content) {

                    _ => self.load(content)

                }

            }

            Err(_) => Result::Err(Error::NoSuchFile),

        }

    }

    // Function to compile the code into intermidiate code (program)
    pub fn parse(&mut self) -> Result<Program, Error> {

        // Create a new program
        let mut prog = Program::new();

        // Create a stack for the loop brackets
        let mut loop_stack = Vec::<usize>::new();

        // Create a code buffer ptr
        let mut code_ptr:usize = 0;

        // Compile the code buffer and feed the program
        if self.code_buffer.len() != 0 {

            loop {

                match self.code_buffer[code_ptr] as char {

                    b @ '+' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ '-' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ '>' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ '<' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ ',' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ '.' => { prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap()); }
                    b @ '[' => { 

                        // Add the instruction to the program (leave 0 for now)
                        prog.push(mapper::get_instr(b).unwrap());

                        // Update the loop stack
                        loop_stack.push(prog.get_size() - 1);

                     }
                    ']' => { 

                        if loop_stack.is_empty() {

                            // Missmatch `]` bracket found
                            return Result::Err(Error::MissingOpenBracket);

                        }

                        let curr_ptr = prog.get_size();

                        let last_open_bracket_ptr = loop_stack.pop().unwrap();

                        prog.update_instr(last_open_bracket_ptr, Instruction::OpenBracket(curr_ptr));

                        prog.push(Instruction::CloseBracket(last_open_bracket_ptr));

                     }
                    _   => { /* IGNORE UNUSED SYMBOLS */ }

                };

                code_ptr += 1;

                if code_ptr >= self.code_buffer.len() {
                    break;
                }

            }

            // Check if loop_stack is empty or not -> not = error (missmatched brackets)
            if !loop_stack.is_empty() {
                return Result::Err(Error::MissingCloseBracket);
            }

        } else {

            // The code buffer is empty -> empty code loaded or just never loaded
            return Result::Err(Error::EmptyProgram);

        }

        // Program is empty return Error (code buffer contains only unused symbols)
        if prog.get_size() == 0 {
            return Result::Err(Error::EmptyProgram);
        }

        return Result::Ok(prog);

    }

}
```

**core/program.rs**

```
use super::instruction::Instruction;

// Struct for the program (a series of instructions)
pub struct Program {

    instr:Vec<Instruction>,
    ptr:usize,

}

impl Program {

    // Function to create and return a new program
    pub fn new() -> Program {

        Program {

            instr:Vec::<Instruction>::new(),
            ptr:0,

        }

    }

    // Function to increase the pointer
    pub fn inc_ptr(&mut self) -> bool {

        if self.ptr < self.instr.len() - 1 {
            self.ptr += 1;
            return true;
        }

        false

    }

    // Function to decrease the pointer
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn dec_ptr(&mut self) -> bool {

        if self.ptr > 0 {
            self.ptr -= 1;
            return true;
        }

        false

    }

    // Function to move the pointer
    pub fn set_ptr(&mut self, pos:usize) -> bool {

        if pos >= self.get_size() {
            return false;
        }

        self.ptr = pos;

        true

    }

    // Function to get the current instruction (if a program is already loaded and the instruction exists)
    pub fn get(&self) -> Option<Instruction> {

        if self.instr.len() > 0 { Option::Some(self.instr[self.ptr]) } else { Option::None }

    }

    // Function to increase the pointer and get the instruction
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn get_next(&mut self) -> Option<Instruction> {

        if self.inc_ptr() { self.get() } else { Option::None }

    }

    // Function to decrease the pointer and get the instruction
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn get_prev(&mut self) -> Option<Instruction> {

        if self.dec_ptr() { self.get() } else { Option::None }

    }

    // Function to get an instruction
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn get_at(&self, p:usize) -> Option<Instruction> {

        if p >= (0 as usize) && p < self.instr.len() { Option::Some(self.instr[p]) } else { Option::None }

    }

    // Function to add a new instruction at the end of the program
    pub fn push(&mut self, i:Instruction) -> &mut Program {

        self.instr.push(i);

        self

    }

    // Function to remove the last instruction from the program (if exists)
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> bool {

        return match self.instr.pop() {

            Some(_) => {

                if self.ptr >= self.instr.len() {
                    if self.ptr > 0 {
                        self.ptr -= 1;
                    }
                }

                true

            }

            None => false

        }

    }

    // Function to clear the program and set pointer to 0
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn clear(&mut self) -> &mut Program {

        self.instr.clear();
        self.ptr = 0;

        self

    }

    // Function to reset the pointer (set to 0)
    #[allow(unused)]
    pub fn reset_ptr(&mut self) -> &mut Program {

        self.ptr = 0;

        self

    }

    // Function to update a specific instruction
    pub fn update_instr(&mut self, pos:usize, new_instr:Instruction) -> bool {

        if self.instr.len() == 0 || pos >= self.instr.len() {
            return false;
        }

        self.instr[pos] = new_instr;

        return true;

    }

    // Function to get program's size
    pub fn get_size(&self) -> usize {

        self.instr.len()

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have a repository for this? It is correct, that you post the code here, but it's a bit cumbersome to scrap the code from this post.

Comment: @hellow Sorry, should I delete this? Yes, I added a link the repository in case it's hard to read the code from the post.

Comment: No! As said, it is the correct way. Always post the related to to stackexchange, so it does not rely on external sources. But it's a extra step so it is easier for me to get and inspect the code, instead of doing copy&paste 8 times and setting up the repo correctly.

Comment: @hellow No worries. My bad, I would think it's a link to wikipedia as well lol

Answer (score 1):

(Please note: that I'm writing this while I walk through your code, so things I spot I will write down. This so can be sometimes a bit difficult to follow, I apologize!)

Rust has pretty good tooling, e.g. [`rustfmt`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt) which ensures, that the code you wrote compiles with the [rust style guidlines](https://github.com/rust-dev-tools/fmt-rfcs). This is the first step you should do (it's pure formatting, does nothing else).

Second, there is [`clippy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) which spots common mistakes in your code, e.g. using `return 3;` as a last statement in a function (which is not recommended, but not actually wrong).

The neat thing is, that this is really painless to install and use.

- `rustup component add clippy rustfmt`

  - installs clippy and rustfmt for your current toolchain
- `cargo rustfmt`

  - formats the code, you may want to commit the code before processing further
- `cargo clippy`

  - Spots common mistakes and potential errors in your code

To highlight some of the things you do which are not considered as *rusty*:

---

```
   --> src/core/parser.rs:129:9
129 |         return Result::Ok(prog);
```

Make this

```rust
Ok(prog)
```

You can omit `return` and espcially `Result`, because it is [in the prelude of `std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/prelude/index.html).
Also do this for other occurences, e.g. `src/core/program.rs:139` and `src/lib.rs:100`. Especially you do `Result::Ok/Err` very often, although you can shorten it to `Ok(...)` or `Err(...)`.

---

Transform

```
src/core/parser.rs:60:12
60 |         if self.code_buffer.len() != 0 {
```

to

```rust
if !self.code_buffer.is_empty() {
```

---

```
src/lib.rs:125:9
    |
125 | match io::stdin().bytes().next() {
126 |     Some(v) => self.tape.set_val(v.unwrap()),
127 | 
128 |     None => {}
129 | }
```

```rust
if let Some(v) = io::stdin().bytes().next() {
    self.tape.set_val(v.unwrap());
}
```

---

You use unwrap quite often. You should either consider using a `Result` or [`{Option,Result}::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) which will panic with a custom message instead of the default one which you can use to explain what went wrong and why. It is considered to be better than using plain unwrap (unless you really, **really** know it cannot fail, but often you should use a `if let` then like I showed above.

---

I would recommend using `#[derive(Debug)]` on types, so debugging is easier. Also provide a [`Default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/default/trait.Default.html) implementation where suiteable, e.g. for `Inter`, `Memory`, `Program` and `Parser`. A rule of thumb is, whenever you have a `new` "constructor" with no arguments, provide a `Default` impl.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
pub struct Inter {
    tape: Memory,
    program: Program,
    parser: Parser,
}
```

---

I would rewrite the `Inter::load` and `Inter::load_from_file` as static methods. In contrast to other OOP-languages rust does not have an explicit constructor and is therefore not bound to a specific return value, so you can have something like `fn new() -> Result<Self, Error>` which is really neat. Or you could provide a method `with_parser` to `Inter`, e.g.

```rust
pub fn with_parser(parser: Parser) -> Self {
    Inter {
        parser,
        ..Default::default()
    }
}
```

This way you would get rid of redudant methods, which is always a good thing!

`Parser::load` would then look similar to

```rust
impl Parser {
    pub fn load<S: Into<String>>(buffer: S) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let buffer = buffer.into().into_bytes();
        if buffer.is_empty() {
            Err(Error::EmptyProgram)?; // or return Err(Error::EmptyProgram);
        }
        Ok(Parser {
            code_buffer: buffer.into_bytes()
        })
    }
}
```

Same goes for `load_from_file`.

---

Your `Inter` does not new the `parser` member at all. You could get rid of it completly, because you only use it for parsing text.
So instead of providing a `new` function without parameters on `Inter`, I would have a function: `pub fn with_program(program: Program) -> Self` which you can call like

```rust
fn run() -> Result<(), Error> {
    let interpreter = Inter::with_program(Parser::load_from_file("/dev/urandom")?.parse()?);
    // ...
}
```

This of course makes it impossible implementing `Default` for `Inter`, unless you want it to be possible to create an empty tape/program (You also could make `Parser::load_from_file` return a `Result<Program, Error>` instead, so you get rid of the extra `parse` call.

---

Why do you parse bytes, instead of chars? You suspect, that you are only getting ascii chars, but what if there is a `ß` or `Õ` in the text you load. This will lead to very weird errors.
Also the function looks very c-ish. You have a lot of mutable variables and index variables. Rust doesn't do that, instead just go with (`self.input` is a `String`): `for c in self.input.chars()`.
Also you can group common actions together, e.g.

```rust
for c in self.code.chars() {
    match c {
        '+' | '-' | '>' | ... /* insert rest here */ => { unimplemented!() },
        _ => { /* the rest */ unimplemented!() },
    }
}
```

These are just a few things, I do not have time (sorry!), but I think you can start with this. If you want I can update it later on with more examples and how to do it differently.